# how to install node 4.4.7 and npm 3.8.9?

Tags: npm

By default node 4.4.7 comes with npm 2.15.8 version. 
How can I modify npm version to 3.8.9 with same node version?

npm update @npm3.8.9 or upgrade didn't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
npm install npm@3.8.9
```

If you want to install latest version of `npm`

```
npm install npm@latest
```

here `latest` is the keyword

We can also upgrade node via `npm`

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

The `n` package represents a `Node helper`, and running the last command upgrades node to the latest stable version.  Instead of using "`stable`", you could specify a desired `version`:

Comment: Thanks John, it worked.
I did try this but didn't work at first place :-D Might have missed there

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade, run: [sudo] `npm install npm@latest -g` if you don't want the latest provide the version number there

Comment: here `-g` is for global installation